# ruler-mode not following fill-column value

Tags: fill-column

With `ruler-mode` enabled and using `(setq fill-column 72)`, I still see the fill-column icon in `ruler-mode` at column `70`.

I want to customise `fill-column` globally or according to major mode.  Can one do this and if so, how?  I have to set these customisations in elisp.

Have done `C-h f setq-default` which states that

```
 The default value of a variable is seen in buffers
 that do not have their own values for the variable.
```

But I want to change the value even if buffer has its own value for `fill-column`.  Meaning that `(setq-default fill-column 72` will not word globally.

Comment: (1) The variable `fill-column` is *buffer-local*, which means that the value can be different in certain buffers depending upon how/where the variable was set -- as such, check the value of `fill-column` in the buffer with `ruler-mode` enabled by type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`.  (2) If the *buffer-local* value of `fill-column` is to your liking, then try manually updating the buffer with `ruler-mode` enabled by typing `C-:` aka `M-x eval-expression` and evaluating `(force-mode-line-update t)`.  Then, update the question if need be to include more details if your problem is not fixed.

Comment: I think that `C-:` in @lawlist's otherwise excellent comment (good enough to be an answer) should be `M-:`.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The variable `fill-column` is *buffer-local*, which means that the value can be different in certain buffers depending upon how/where the variable was set -- as such, check the value of `fill-column` in the buffer with `ruler-mode` enabled by typig `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`. (2) If the *buffer-local* value of `fill-column` is to your liking, then try manually updating the header-line of the buffer with `ruler-mode` enabled by typing `M-:` aka `M-x eval-expression` and evaluating `(force-mode-line-update t)`. [If this answer is insufficient to assist in resolving the issue, then go ahead and update the question to include more details ....]